# Uploading files to Google Drive using Drive API without consent screen

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, drive

I am creating a Node.js Express application for a customer where he wants his users to upload files from the application into his google drive. Then his team (who is part of the gsuite) can review the files.

I researched about Google Drive API v3 and it seems I need to implement some form of consent screen (like login with your google account) to get access to the drive. However not all the users who upload the files will have access to the gsuite account (they are contractors who are not part of the company).

So ideally what I am looking for is a Google Drive implementation that will act like AWS S3 - api wise. So it should just ask for an API key (of the primary gsuite account) and no OAuth or user consent/login screen.

Is this possible? What are my options?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, when you want to upload files to your Google Drive without authorization, as a workaround, how about using Web Apps of Google Apps Script? When Web Apps is used, the file can be uploaded without authorization by using the script of Node.js, and can be used like an API. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: So add my node.js app as a app in the Google Apps?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about `So add my node.js app as a app in the Google Apps? `? I couldn't understand it.

Comment: So I have seen that in dropbox or box.com you have to add your app to your account which then gives you access to the storage. I wanted to ask if thats what you were recommending.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In the case of Web Apps, such situation is not required. You can directly upload files to your Google Drive without authorization using request of node.js. If you want to give the password, you can do it like API key and OAuth2. The official document of Web Apps is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web As a limitation, if you want to upload the file of the size more than 50 MB, the resumable upload is required to be used.

Comment: @codeinprogress been wanting to do the same, have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @AivanMonceller no we went the S3 route. But I will do a POC on this issue the coming weekend and see if it works.